# Is there any way I can lock up Endermen for a zoo, without them escaping?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Or anything I can do to keep them from disappearing, like wearing a pumpkin? Or redstone?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enderman#Teleportation):

> An enderman cannot teleport when it is in a minecart, though in rain
> and water it will attempt to do so, always teleporting back into the
> minecart repeatedly until death.
>
> Endermen will not teleport in the daytime while on soul sand unless they are damaged.

You can either put them into a minecart, or put them on top of soul sand.

If you have enough room, you could make walls at least 32 blocks thick in all directions:

> When teleporting, endermen search for an air block within 32 blocks along each axis...

You could even strand them on an island surrounded by 32 blocks of water or lava:

> Endermen will never teleport into water or lava.

but remember that they can teleport up or down as well.